# Boost enable/disable_if function pair's order matters?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm writing a recursive function whose end condition is determined by template parameters.  I'm using `boost::enable_if` and `boost::disable_if` to switch out the recursive function for an empty base case (to prevent that tiresome infinite instantiation loop).
The problem is that it seems to depend on the order which I define these functions:

```
    #include <boost/utility.hpp>

    template <unsigned a, unsigned b>
    typename boost::disable_if_c<a == b>::type f()
    {
        f<a+1,b>();
    }

    template <unsigned a, unsigned b>
    typename boost::enable_if_c<a == b>::type f()
    {
    }

    int main()
    {
        f<0,5>();
    }
```

the compiler (g++4.6) fails with the error:

```
    test.cpp:7:5: error: no matching function for call to ‘f()’
    test.cpp:7:5: note: candidate is:
    test.cpp:5:44: note: template<unsigned int a, unsigned int b> typename boost::disable_if_c<(a == b)>::type f()
```

for some reason there's only the disabled function as a candidate, the enabled one isn't seen.

If I switch the order the two functions are defined it compiles with issue and without warnings:

```
    #include <boost/utility.hpp>

    template <unsigned a, unsigned b>
    typename boost::enable_if_c<a == b>::type f()
    {
    }

    template <unsigned a, unsigned b>
    typename boost::disable_if_c<a == b>::type f()
    {
        f<a+1,b>();
    }

    int main()
    {
        f<0,5>();
    }
```

Why is this?  By the time the instantiation happens (in `main`) the compiler has seen both functions and shouldn't care who got in line first.  At least that's what I thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say

> By the time the instantiation happens (in main) the compiler has seen both functions and shouldn't care who got in line first.

This is not true and I think that's what's tripping you up. What's instantiated in main is just `f<0,5>`, the rest of instantiations happen where you call them, inside first `f` function template. The second one isn't visible from there so it can't participate in overload resolution.

So, what happens:

```
// imagine we're inside f<4,5> instantiation

template <unsigned a, unsigned b>
typename boost::disable_if_c<a == b>::type f()
{
    f<a+1,b>(); // <-- here we attempt to instantiate f<5,5> ...
                // but it gets disabled!

    // and there is no other f visible here, it's defined just below
}
```

If you switch the order of definitions, the `enable_if` version is visible and it kicks in when needed.

Comment: After thinking about this some more, I think I'm confused because I thought that `f` was a dependent name because it was a template.  Is this not the case?  If not then I am in complete agreement because then `f<a+1,b>();` is resolved at the template's definition and not at the its instantiation later on.

Comment: No, a name of a template is not a dependent name. Even if it were, it's point of instantiation would be the scope of first `f` and it still couldn't bind `f` to the second template.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting mixed up by fact that your functions are templates. That doesn't have anything to do with it. The following also doesn't compile, and for the same reason.

```
void foo(int)
{
  foo("");
}

void foo(char const*)
{
}

int main()
{
  foo(42);
}
```

Order matters.

Comment: Yeah, that's it in a nutshell